# LocationListener triggers before the interval set in location request using gms android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to trigger locationChanged method for tracking real time location. I use below code to achieve this. My question is I gave **interval of 5** seconds but the **location changed method triggers at every 3 seconds**. I tried changing priority but its the same. What mistake I have done understanding its logic ? Thank you in advance for guidance.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
            //tried high accuracy also thinking it might matter with priority but doesn't effect            
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(5 * 1000);
```

**Method which triggers location request.**

```
private void requestLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, locationListener);
        else
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, locationListener);

        Log.d(TAG, "requestLocation: ");
    }
}
```

**locationListener instance.**

```
 LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

       //log shows this triggering at every 3 seconds.
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: ");

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I can achieve the 5 second triggering by putting interval to 10 seconds, but I want to understand why this time difference is there ?

Comment: why down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` combined with a faster `setFastestInterval(long)` and a slower `setInterval(long)` interval. U can use both or `setFastestInterval(long)` as described in [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long))

Comment: thank u.. it works well, but still giving 5 seconds for both and listener triggers at 6 or 5 seconds... but close to perfection so its enough..